# Gradle - declare one dependency to pull from m2 repo

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project, but my actual work is in a dependency to that project.  I'm trying to have my gradle project pull my local work contained in my m2 repo, but I only want to pull **THAT** particular dependency from my local environment, everything else I want to be pulled as it would be from my deployed test environment, so I want to avoid just declaring `mavenLocal()` in my build script.  Is there a way to specify for gradle to pull one dependency from my local maven cache, and everything else should be as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thing called **repository filtering**:

```
mavenLocal().content {
  // this repository *only* contains artifacts with group "my.company"
  includeGroup "my.company"
}
```

More info can be found on [gradle's website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-content-filtering).